# Error en una Función

Tags: java, json, eclipse

tengo un problema.
Tengo una clase creada de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Product extends Model {

public String productid;
public String model;
public String brand;
public Double price;
public Integer min_weight;
public Integer max_weight;
public Integer min_height;
public Integer max_height;
//public String image;

public Product(String productid, String model, String brand, Double price, Integer min_weight, 
        Integer max_weight, Integer min_height, Integer max_height)
{
    this.productid = productid;
    this.model = model;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.price = price;
    this.min_weight = min_weight;
    this.max_weight = max_weight;
    this.min_height = min_height;
    this.max_height = max_height;
}
```

Cuando ejecuto la siguiente función, el servidor no me da error pero no me devuelve lo esperado.
El funcionamiento de la función es el siguiente: cada producto tiene una altura máxima y mínima, un peso máximo y mínimo y un precio. En la función recibo como parámetro un peso, una altura y un precio. La altura y el peso deben encontrarse entre el valor maximo y el minimo de altura (height) y peso (weight) respectivamente. El precio introducido por parámetro debe ser superior al del producto.
Esta es la función:

```
public void getresults(Double price, Integer height, Integer weight)
{
    List<Product> l2 = Product.findAll();
    int i=0;
    while (i<l2.size())
    {
        if ((height>l2.get(i).max_height)||(height<l2.get(i).min_height))
        {
            l2.remove(i);
        }
        else if ((weight>l2.get(i).max_weight)||(weight<l2.get(i).min_weight))
        {
            l2.remove(i);
        }
        else if (price < l2.get(i).price)
        {
            l2.remove(i);
        }

        i++;            
    }
    renderJSON(l2);
}
```

Gracias,

Comment: Podrias indicar que error te da exactamente?

Comment: y qué te da como respuesta?

Comment: cuidado con el remove, ya que el ciclo while está evaluando el tamaño del vector y este está disminuyendo a medida que avanza, te recomiendo colocar el tamaño del vector en una variable aparte: int x = l2.size() y usar esta x en el while.

Comment: Te recomiendo no modificar la lista que obtenés del findAll(), ¿por qué no preguntas por el positivo y armas una nueva lista que contiene los datos filtrados? o por qué no filtras a nivel de datos ?.

Saludos

Comment: ERROR FUNCION JAVA es demasiado vago. Sería más fácil ayudarte si tu pregunta es específica.

Comment: Como bien dice @CrismanCarmona, ese bucle no puede funcionar correctamente ya que estas eliminando elementos de la lista al mismo tiempo que lo recorres. Es mejor que uses un bucle `for` regresivo, es decir desde `l2.size() -1` hasta `0`: `for(int i=l2.size() - 1; i>= 0;i--)`

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaciones:

- Escribe un nuevo método: Product.findByPriceHeightAndWeight() y modifica el query que trae los datos de manera que incluya tus condiciones.
- Si no puedes cambiar el query debes usar un iterador para evitar resultados inconsistentes en la lista.

Ejemplo de iterador:

```
        Iterator<Product> it = Product.findAll().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Product p = it.next();
            if(
                (weight < p.min_weight || weight > p.max_weight) ||
                (height < p.min_height || height > p.max_height) ||
                (price < p.price)
              ) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
```